# animate two properties within same duration

Tags: javascript, animation

I am building my own animation library; here is the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/rrqe4qh1/).

The problem is when I try to animate multiple properties the animation is finished as soon as the property with the last value is satisfied.  For example:

I want to change an element's `top` and `left` properties to 500 and 300, respectively.  The animation completes with both `top` and `left` as 300.  This is incorrect.

My code structure resembles the following:

Main animate function:

```
function animate(ele,prop,duration,easing,callback) {
    //...
}
```

Animation manager:

```
function Animation() {
    this.start = function(ele,prop,duration,easing,callback) {
        new animate(ele,prop,duration,easing,callback).start();
    };
}
```

Please let me know how can solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/rrqe4qh1/1/

while applying the styles

```
   this.ele.style[k]= val + 'px';
```

It was conflicting with style values of other properties as well

adding the below check helped

```
   if(e===k)  this.ele.style[k]= val + 'px';
```